# Error in models folder "doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I can't find a solution for the following error:

RuntimeError: Model class users.models.User.User doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

The INSTALLED_APPS:

```
LOCAL_APPS = [
    "api.users",
    "api.achievements",
    "api.others",
]
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps
INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS
```

Models folder

`users/models/__init__.py`:

```
from .User import *  # noqa
from .Profile import *  # noqa
```

`users/models/User.py`:

```
""" User related models """

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

from api.others.constants import GENDER


class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Default custom user model for Dezumi API.
    If adding fields that need to be filled at user signup,
    check forms.SignupForm and forms.SocialSignupForms accordingly.
    """

    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    country = CountryField(null=True, blank=True, blank_label='Select country')
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER, max_length=6, null=True, blank=True)

    is_verified = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
    )

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Get url for user's detail view.

        Returns:
            str: URL for user detail.

        """
        return reverse("users:detail", kwargs={"username": self.username})
```

The app is on installed_apps, so what could it be? Something with the **init**.py?

Directory Structure:

```
api
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── users
│   │   ├── admin
│   │   ├── api
│   │   │   ├── serializers.py
│   │   │   └── views.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── models
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── Profile.py
│   │   │   └── User.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   └── ...
│   └── ...
├── config
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── local.py
│   │   ├── production.py
│   │   └── test.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── ...
├── requirements
├── utility
├── manage.py
└── ...
```

Log:

```
  File "path\api\api\users\admin\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .Profile import *  # noqa
  File "path\api\api\users\admin\Profile.py", line 3, in <module>
    from users.models.Profile import Profile
  File "path\api\api\users\models\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .User import *  # noqa
  File "path\api\api\users\models\User.py", line 11, in <module>
    class User(AbstractUser):
  File "path\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 113, in __new__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Model class users.models.User.User doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

apps.py from users

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "api.users"
    verbose_name = _("Users")

    def ready(self):
        try:
            import api.users.signals  # noqa F401
        except ImportError:
            pass
```

Comment: share your directory structure?

Comment: already added directory structure, its from the django cookiecutter

Comment: Share your `apps.py` file. I expect that you did not set `name` of `UserConfig` class.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly referencing the Users app configuration class might work:

```
LOCAL_APPS = [
    "api.users.apps.UsersConfig",
    ...
]
```